# AutoHotkey Script for repeating key in background chrome tab

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

So what I want to do is when I press on a key A/B L/R/U/D I want to send that keystroke both to whatever I'm working on as well as to [this](https://weplay.io) Pokemon yellow game. Here's the script so far:

```
Left::
Send {Left}
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinName = weplay
WinClass = Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1
WinText = Chrome Legacy Window 
ControlSend, %WinClass%, {Left}, %WinName%, %WinText%
return
```

However, this script only works when the weplay tab is open. How can I make it so I can work in one window while sending my keystrokes to a weplay background tab in chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a weird behavior with how Chrome renders its window. To get around this you can use this script:

```
Left::
    Send, {Left}
    ControlFocus, Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1, ahk_exe Chrome.exe
    ControlSend, ahk_parent, {Left}, ahk_exe Chrome.exe
return
```

It solves the problem by first sending a `ControlFocus` command to Chrome and then uses a `ControlSend` command using `ahk_parent` to target the entire window instead of any particular control.

You can read more here:

- [ControlFocus](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ControlFocus.htm)
- [ControlSend (See 'Control' param for ahk_parent)](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm)

Comment: This doesn't work though if chrome is minimized

Comment: @MrEngineer13 Yeah, that's due to how Chrome renders again. They changed something a few version back which broke a lot of scripts interacting with it. It should work fine in Firefox however, if that is an option.

Comment: Actually I'm using a similar script in IE and it's working fine